FPS hands recoil
I am working on FPS game. I have created few animations in blender.I started working on weapon shooting and understood that for that one I need procedural recoil.I created a script that generates recoil but the thing is that a can't influence hands with that recoil as the weapon is a child of a right hand. I would like to affect both hands by the gun's recoil.
If I use Animation Rigging IK and use Multi-Rotation constraint than hand is coping rotation of the gun but with slight delay and the more gun rotates the more the gap is between hand and gun.
I saw that another possible solution would be to make hands a child of a gun but I don't like this approach. Also it would break my current animations.
Here is my current structure. I instantiate a weapon from weapon slots for currently active slot under WeaponHolder. The script for recoil is attached to the gun prefab.


